# How to serialize object rather than stringify when using ForContext

Tags: c#, serilog

I want to support serializing additional relevant data with a Serilog log but I want to ensure that this data is written in valid JSON. It will be captured and stored separately by my own log event sink.

For this example I have an optional object property called "additionalDetails"

I can use the following to write the log information and the additionalDetails can be extracted as JSON:

```
int messageId = 99;
var additionalDetails = new {SomeId = 1, SomeValue = "This is a test value"};
logger.Information("Test Log Entry: {messageId} Additional Details: {@additionalDetails}", 
    messageId, additionalDetails);
```

In my Sink I can retrieve the "additionalDetails" as JSON from the logEvent.Properties and write it. However, I don't want to necessarily include the AdditionalDetails in every log message text.

What I would like is:

```
int messageId = 99;
var additionalDetails = new {SomeId = 1, SomeValue = "This is a test value"};
logger
    .ForContext("additionalDetails", additionalDetails)
    .Information("Test Log Entry: {messageId}", 
    messageId);
```

The problem here is that while the Sink can see the additionalDetails value, it isn't coming back as valid JSON, but the default stringified value. For unit testing I am validating that the stored object is complete, which puts a bit of a blocker if I cannot convert that stringified value back into an object.

On a whim I tried: `.ForContext("@additionalDetails", additionalDetails)` and "{@additionalDetails}" but that was no joy.

I also found a recommendation to write the object as a string using `JsonConvert.Serialize(additionalDetails)` but that ended up causing extra quote escaping in the resulting string captured by the Sink `logEvent.Properties["additionalDetails"].ToString()`.

Is there a way that `ForContext` can serialize an object like with the "{@additionalDetails}", or include the "{@additionalDetails}" and parameter in the `.Information()` etc. calls without the parameter being rendered in the message? (sounds rather silly round-about)

Answer (score 0):

The solution actually looks to be using the `destructureObjects` option on the ForContext, which reading into the option is essentially what the @ was doing:

```
var additionalDetails = new { SomeId = 1, SomeValue = "This is a test value." };
log
    .ForContext("additionalDetails", additionalDetails, true)
    .Information(messageTemplate, messageId, destination);
```

In my Sink I am looking for the additionalDetails and persisting it, expecting a JSON string, or at least a value that can be de-serialized:

```
 string? additionalDetails = logEvent.Properties.ContainsKey("additionalDetails")
     ? logEvent.Properties["additionalDetails"].ToString()
     : null;
```

(Right now there are magic strings but I will be re-factoring this out)

My tests for the Sink uses the Serilog logger initialized with an instance of the Sink that is configured with a mocked entity for the Log entry (rather than writing to the database) so I want to log the test entry then inspect the mocked entity's AdditionalDetails property, deserialize that and ensure the values are persisted:

```
Assert.That(mockedLog.AdditionalDetails, Is.Not.Null);
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(mockedLog.AdditionalDetails)!;
Assert.That(obj, Is.Not.Null);
Assert.Multiple(() =>
{
    Assert.That(obj.SomeId, Is.EqualTo(details.SomeId));
    Assert.That(obj.SomeValue, Is.EqualTo(details.SomeValue));
});
```

Which now works perfectly without writing the AdditionalDetails to the log text. The AdditionalDetails is enabled at runtime to be able to serialize useful information such as a DTO sent for an Update/Insert operation (not intended for heavy object graphs since this system is designed around more atomic operations) Still I want to separate the log message from this optional data.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [the `ILogEventEnricher` trick Nick showed me](https://github.com/jet/equinox/blob/796a0eac5f7a43c5d80e24c225c71a802a6961aa/src/Equinox.Core/Internal.fs#L6-L10) in [Serilog issue 1124](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1124):

```
class ScalarValueEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    readonly LogEventProperty _prop;

    public ScalarValueEnricher(string name, object value)
    {
        _prop = new LogEventProperty(name, new ScalarValue(value));
    }

    public void Enrich(LogEvent evt, ILogEventPropertyFactory _)
    {
         evt.AddPropertyIfAbsent(_prop);
    }
}
```

Like so:

```
using (LogContext.Push(new ScalarValueEnricher("esEvt", value))
    Log.Information("This has a scalar attached..");
```

Then you can extract or render, possibly with the help of another enricher.